# Update on keys empty columns, identical keys, most recent date

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have a table that will everyone year or so have information loaded into it. We have hardcorded certain fields (line,type,quality) which is not found in the raw data being loaded into the table. As you see below the line, type and quality are all empty for 2015. How can i Update the 2015 row with the line, type and quality from the most recent year with the same account name and type?

```
as_of   account name    line    type    quality
2014    1   steve          1    medium  medium
2013    1   steve          1    big     wide
2015    1   steve           
2014    2   dave           2    small   narrow
2015    2   dave            
2014    3   carl           3    medium  medium
2015    3   carl
```

My update SQL statements are returning "must use an updateable query"

Answer (score 0):

So,
I was able to fix this, heh.

I had to select the as_of date in a combo box and select all dates less than the date I wanted to be updated, storied in a view.

I then Selected the max date of all results where the account name was the unique identifier, this returned the most recent record with line, type and quality entries, this is stored as a table.

I was then able to update from the created table to the main table the line type and quality values.

Geeze, that's a hassle, especially in Access.

Anyone know a better way? Thanks